# Display Metadata navigation and filter without also showing the quick launch (SP2010)

Tags: sharepoint, treeview

I'm currently displaying the Metadata navigation in my custom master page using the Delegate Control, pointing it at the treeviewdatasource control. It works, but it also ends up rendering the quicklaunch treeview as well.

How can I have the Metadata navigation without the quicklaunch? Is it supposed to show that?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: All I had was the DelegateControl with the treeview. I needed the full SharePoint:UIVersionContent control from V4 master page to properly display/hide my quick launch and treeview.